# Can I make calendar items link to data view page?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, upgrade, calendar

We currently upgraded from 2007 to 2010 and I'm having problems with the calendar. In 2007 I was able to change that the calendar items would link to a custom data view I created.

Here is our 2007 page that displays the calendar:

http://www.colostate-pueblo.edu/Communications/Events/Pages/default.aspx

Here is our 2007 page with the view:

http://www.colostate-pueblo.edu/Communications/Events/Pages/eventdisplay.aspx?EventID=1299

After we upgraded I'm getting a "404 NOT FOUND" page when I click on a calendar item. Is there any way to have the calendar item open in a custom data view I've created?

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint Designer 2010, you can specify the default display pages for the view, edit, and new item forms. I would use this to specify your custom page.